# WCF callback service to php client

Tags: php, javascript, asp.net, wcf, soap-client

I have created a WCF Service with callback and using wsDualHttp Binding.
I want to connect to this service using PHP client. 
In PHP , SoapClient is used to call the WCF service like below:

```
$wsdl = "http://pathto/file.svc?wsdl"
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('trace' => $trace, 'exceptions' => $exceptions));
$response = $client->somefunction();
```

Please guide in getting for callback in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, but IMO its impossible to have callback from wcf to php (for exaple, this post also say so: 
http://wso2.org/forum/thread/24111).

Probably you can check for some websocket solution to receive behavior you ste looking for.

Take a look on node.js, for ecample: http://bergie.iki.fi/blog/dnode-make_php_and_node-js_talk_to_each_other/